# Symmetrical endomorphisms and quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

(This last part of my linear algebra course is causing me quite a bit of headaches, so please be patient)

Let $V$ be a vector space over the real field, and we'll indicate with $(\cdot,\cdot)$ its scalar product (that we'll assume defined positive). If $T:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a symmetrical endomorphism, the function $\phi:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(v)=(T(v),v)$ is a quadratic form.

Ok, so this is a theorem on my linear algebra textbook. ...What? Wasn't a quadratic form one of the form $\phi(v)=(v,v)$? What does it mean to arbitrarily put $T(v)$ there?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I bet you meant "linear" or "vector" instead "metric"...

Comment: Erase the "metric" since I think you mean "a vector space with inner product"...

Comment: Doesn't every scalar product naturally define the concept of distance? What is wrong with saying "metric" apart from some redundancy?

Comment: Because "metric space" belongs to a realm that has nothing to do with the question in this context, and it is not standard usage and can mislead...and no: a general inner product does not necessarily define a concept of distance.

Comment: @DonAntonio , are you including bilinear forms that are not positive definite in the set “scalar products”?

Comment: Oh, I think I see where you're going, @pppqqq. Well, yes: if we *only* take pos. def. bilinear forms as inner product, then indeed inner product yields a metric space. Nice you commented, this may clear up things. I was thinking of general bilinear forms.Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, I know it's just a matter of definitions, but it can possibly cause confusion.

Comment: I was indeed referring to symmetrical bilinear forms defined positive. As I learned a few days ago, this is the standard usage in anglophone countries of the word "scalar product", right? Anyway, this non-omogeneity of definitions is really quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quadratic form on a real vector space $V$ is a map $Q:V\to\Bbb R$ such that there exists *some* symmetrical bilinear form $\phi:V\times V\to \Bbb R$ with the property that for all vectors $X\in V$, 
$$Q(X)=\phi(X,X)$$
This symmetrical bilinear form doesn't have to be a scalar product, nor the scalar product with which you are currently working with.

To convince yourself that the theorem is true, you only need to convince yourself that the map
$$\phi:V\times V\to \Bbb R,\quad (X,Y)\mapsto\phi(X,Y)=\langle TX,Y\rangle$$
is indeed a symmetrical bilinear form. Bilinearity is obvious, and symmetry follows at once from the definition of a symmetric endomorphism, and symmetry of the underlying scalar product (which I renamed $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to distinguish it from the parantheses of pairs of elements.)

Answer (score 2):

Choose an **orthonormal** basis $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ of $\;V\;$ consisting of eigenvectors of $\;T\;$ , say $\;Tv_i=\lambda iv_i\;,\;\;\lambda_i\in\Bbb R\;$ (why does there exist such a basis?), and express $\;v=\sum_{k=1}^na_kv_k\in V\;$ , then

$$Tv=\sum_{k=1}^na_kTv_k=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\lambda_kv_k\implies $$

$$\langle Tv,v\rangle=\sum_{k,j=1}^na_ka_j\langle Tv_k,v_j\rangle=\sum_{k,j=1}^na_ka_j\lambda_k\delta_{k,j}=\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\lambda _k$$

and there you go....